# java script событие

Tags: javascript, события

Когда я нажимаю на кнопку создается элемент с текстом и резко исчезает.

В чем проблема?

http://plnkr.co/edit/pTMdB3vkXE1epPFJ42xa?p=preview

```
<form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="to do" id="name">
    <button  id="button2">ДОБАВИТЬ </button>
</form>
<ol id="list">

</ol>
<script>
  button2.onclick = function() {
    var newLi = document.createElement('li');
    newLi.innerHTML = 'Привет, мир!';
    list.appendChild(newLi);
  };
</script>
```

Comment: на этой же странице сделал в консоли так var newLi = document.createElement('li'); header.appendChild(newLi); и все норм

Comment: у меня данный код работает корректно

Comment: вписать `return false;` после строки  `list.appendChild(newLi);`

Comment: Ох, хочу вернуться в те времена, когда меня интересовали такие легкие вопросы :3 А не решать шарады с контекстом вызова в js.

Comment: @VostokSisters ох, хочу вернуться во времена когда контекст вызова в js был для меня шарадой :)

Answer (score 3):

Проблема в поведении тега `button`.

В случае, если ему не указан `type`, по умолчанию используется `type="submit"`. Если кнопка находится внутри тега `form`, то при клике на нее в таком случае будет осуществлена отправка формы и страница будет перезагружена.

Для решения проблемы можно воспользоваться одним из следующих путей:

1. Вынести кнопку из тега `form`.

   ```js
   button2.onclick = function() {
     var newLi = document.createElement('li');
     newLi.innerHTML = 'Привет, мир!';
     list.appendChild(newLi);
   };
   ```

   ```html
   <input type="text" placeholder="to do" id="name">
   <button id="button2">ДОБАВИТЬ</button>
   <ol id="list">

   </ol>
   ```
2. выставить атрибут `type` в значение `button`

   ```js
   button2.onclick = function() {
     var newLi = document.createElement('li');
     newLi.innerHTML = 'Привет, мир!';
     list.appendChild(newLi);
   };
   ```

   ```html
   <form>
     <input type="text" placeholder="to do" id="name">
     <button type="button" id="button2">ДОБАВИТЬ</button>
   </form>
   <ol id="list">

   </ol>
   ```
3. Отменить стандартное поведение, вызвав [метод `preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

   ```js
   button2.onclick = function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var newLi = document.createElement('li');
     newLi.innerHTML = 'Привет, мир!';
     list.appendChild(newLi);
   };
   ```

   ```html
   <form>
     <input type="text" placeholder="to do" id="name">
     <button id="button2">ДОБАВИТЬ</button>
   </form>
   <ol id="list">

   </ol>
   ```

Comment: мне кажется, что лучше оставить кнопку, но слушать событие `submit` на форме, ведь `submit` имеет ряд преимуществ, например, нажатие кнопки `enter` на текстовом инпуте

Comment: @Umer, не уверен, что тут вообще нужна форма.

Answer (score 0):

Если вписать `return false;` после строки  `list.appendChild(newLi);` и скрипт закончится после добавления елемента.

```
<script>
  button2.onclick = function() {
   var newLi = document.createElement('li');
  newLi.innerHTML = 'Привет, мир!';

  list.appendChild(newLi);
  return false;
  };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас при нажатие на кнопку, происходит событие submit и браузер пытается отправить get запрос. Вам нужно отменить это событие.

```js
const button2 = document.querySelector('#button2');

button2.onclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var newLi = document.createElement('li');
    newLi.innerHTML = 'Привет, мир!';
    list.appendChild(newLi);
 };
```

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="to do" id="name">
    <button  id="button2">ДОБАВИТЬ </button>
</form>
<ol id="list">

</ol>
```

Comment: а где там `submit`?

Comment: @tCode, по умолчанию значение атрибута `type` у кнопки - `submit`

Comment: @Grundy спасибо за пояснение, не знал

Comment: @Grundy если кнопка в `form` ..

Comment: @C.Raf.T, что _если кнопка в form_?

Comment: @Grundy походу человек не прочитал ваш ответ на пол страницы)

Comment: @DimenSi, ответ на самом деле 5 строчек, остальное просто сниппеты высокие

Comment: @Grundy пардон, не увидел ваш ответ...

Comment: @C.Raf.T, На самом деле, от нахождения или не нахождения кнопки внутри формы, дефолтное значение для атрибута не изменяется.

Comment: @Grundy https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535211(v=vs.85).aspx#code-snippet-1

Comment: @C.Raf.T, что должна показывать данная ссылка?

Comment: @Grundy  чуть выше.  "Windows Internet Explorer 8 and later. The default value of the type attribute depends on the current document compatibility mode. In IE8 Standards mode, the default value is submit. In other compatibility modes and earlier versions of Windows Internet Explorer, the default value is button."

Comment: @C.Raf.T, На это можно ответить лишь ссылкой на спецификацию: [The missing value default is the Submit Button state.](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-button-element)

Comment: @C.Raf.Tпо-моему это жесть, вы нас пытаетесь тыкать носом в реалии 20 века

Comment: @DimenSi выразил мнение и все...

Comment: @DimenSi, это кстати хороший намек всегда явно указывать нужные атрибуты

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" placeholder="to do" value="" id="name">
<button  id="button2">ДОБАВИТЬ </button>
```

button2.onclick = function() {
    var newLi = document.createElement('li');
    newLi.innerHTML = document.getElementById('name').value;
    list.appendChild(newLi);
  };